# How to keep a div within a div

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

PLease help!

This is what I have so far: http://beauxlent.com/nicole
When you click "one" "two" or "three", it takes you to a div that is still on the same page. However, I would like the div to stay within the right div and still on the same page used #tags. I've seen this done before.

```
<style type="text/css">
 {    
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
text-align: justify;
overflow: hidden;
background: #F8F8F8;
font: -blocked- arial;
}
table, p {
display: none;
}
div {
width: 100%;
}

.container {width: 800px; display:block; margin:0px auto}

.left {width:200px; float:left; background: #eee; display:block; height:200px; 
line-        height:2}


.right {width:600px; float:right; background: #808080; display:block; height: 200px; 
line-height:2; }

#o {position:absolute; right: 2000px;}


.blog {
background: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 500px;
width: 290px;
height: 140px;
}
#omg { 
z-index: 7;
position: absolute;
top: 1000px;
right: 0;
color: #000;
height: 1000px;
}
#plz {

z-index: 7;
position: absolute;
top: 9000px;
right: 0;
color: #000;
height: 9000px;
}

}
#nande a:hover {
color: #000;
}
#nande {

z-index: 7;
position: absolute;
top: 7000px;
right: 0;
color: #000;
height: 1000px;
}
body, table {
color: #fff;
}
font, table, tr, td, br, p {
font: -blocked- franklin gothic medium;
color: #fff;
}
#content {
width: 100%;
    }
#main, #content {
border: 0px none;
background: #fff;
}

}

.framed {
background: #fff;
padding: 5px;

overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0px;
}

</style>
<div id="boxed">







<div class="container">





<div class="left">




<a href="#uno" class="big">1</a>

<a href="#dos" class="big">2</a>


<a href="#tres" class="big">3</a>




</div>



<div class="right">


<div id="omg">
<a name="uno"></a>
<div class="framed">
 one
</div>


</div>



<div id="nande">
<a name="dos"></a>
<div class="framed">
 two
</div>
</div>


<div id="plz">
<a name="tres"></a>
<div class="framed">


three
</div>
</div>



</div>
```

Comment: and i'd like the left sidebar to stay on the screen. right now it doesn't stay and it goes off the screen

Comment: Could you point us to an example of what it is you are trying to accomplish? I am assuming you want the content in each of the divs (#omg #nande #plz) to appear within the #right div when the user clicks the link? Javascript/jQuery is going to be your friend here, but you will have to add a unique id/class to the divs you want to hide/show.

Answer (score 2):

Tabbings you mean. This can be done too in CSS. Try to check it here -> http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/

HTML code:

```
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Due note that this solution is not compatible with IE versions below 9. For a fallback, you might want to use something like Twitter Bootstrap's [tabs.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Comment: @lota yes you have a point. This might not work in IE so better be add the Twitter Bootstrap or any jquery code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) - very easy to implement.

**Include**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
</div>
```